# Accidentally exposed ngrok authtoken; what now?

Tags: security, ngrok

I accidentally exposed my ngrok authtoken. What can be done now to avoid that causing problems? Can I regenerate the token?

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate your authtoken in the dashboard > Admin > Dangerous Operations section, apparently